# How to get the filesize of excel created with phpspreadsheet?

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I wonder if we are able to get the file size of an excel created from `phpspreadsheet`. If it's possible, how can I do that? Thanks for the help.

Comment: does not mater how the file was created: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php

Comment: have you tried `filesize()` ? I know right what an obscure name for getting the size of a file.  Who would guess they would use that.  As a note excel has a habit of locking the file when it's open, so make sure it's closed before trying to access it with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

In the following `$fileName` is a string with the full path to the file you want to know about. It's usually wise to check that any variable you plan to use is valid for the intended use.

```
if (is_file($filename))
{
    $fileSize = filesize($filename);
}
```

[RTM](http://www.php.net/filesize)

Comment: the file_exists call is redundant

Comment: @hanshenrik, Right you are.